# Oscillation frequency of ring oscillator

Tags: frequency, homework, oscillation

I have the following problem, that may be very simple, though I'm not quite sure.

> [image]

**MY ATTEMPT**

Well, if we interpret all the sum of the delays as the period of the oscillation then the answer becomes awfully simple (maybe too easy).

\$f=\frac{1}{T}=\frac{1}{15 \text{ns}+15\text{ns}+15\text{ns}+10\text{ns}+15\text{ns}}=14.286 \text{MHz} \$

I arrive at an answer of 14.29MHz. However, this solution seems way too easy and simple, so I'm wondering if I am understanding the problem correctly?

Can anyone help me tell me if I am on the right track, or if I am way off?

Comment: Yo need two turns for each period.

Comment: @TEMLIB - Could you elaborate a bit, cause I'm not quite sure I understand why that is. Does it have something to do with rising and falling edges?

Comment: It has to do with the fact that your ring is inverting.

Comment: @Andyaka - Oh I see. So because there is an odd number, the signal is inverted after only one turn. So after two turns it is non-inverted, correct? And that must result in the frequency being halved. So \$f=\frac{1}{2} \cdot 14.286 \text{MHz}=7.14 \text{MHz} \$. Am I getting it right?

Comment: I believe so...

Comment: Great, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Picture taken from [this site](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/generators.html)

For this basic design you have to use an odd number of inverters to get negative feedback at DC and thus the circuit becomes self biased.

Comment: Yes, using the formula for frequency seen the right in the picture yields the same answer as I got in the comments.